# How do I use a Peekable iterator in a filter closure?

Tags: iterator, rust

I need to find only the numbers where the next number is the same:  `[1,2,2,3,4,4]` should produce `[2,4]`. Since I need to peek at the next number, I figured I'd try out using a [`Peekable` iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html) and write a `filter`.

```
fn main() {
    let xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4];
    let mut iter = xs.iter().peekable();

    let pairs = iter.filter(move |num| {
        match iter.peek() {
            Some(next) => num == next,
            None       => false,
        }
    });

    for num in pairs {
        println!("{}", num);
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0382]: capture of moved value: `iter`
 --> src/main.rs:6:15
  |
5 |     let pairs = iter.filter(move |num| {
  |                 ---- value moved here
6 |         match iter.peek() {
  |               ^^^^ value captured here after move
  |
  = note: move occurs because `iter` has type `std::iter::Peekable<std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I think this is because `iter` is being used by the closure, but it hasn't borrowed it, and it can't copy it.

How do I solve this problem of wanting to refer to the iterator inside a filter?

Answer (score 4):

> refer to the iterator inside a filter

I don't believe you can. When you call `filter`, it takes ownership of the base iterator:

```
fn filter<P>(self, predicate: P) -> Filter<Self, P> 
where
    P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool,
```

Once you do that, it's gone. There is no more `iter`. In some similar cases, you can use [`Iterator::by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) to mutably borrow the iterator, drive it for a while, then refer back to the original. That won't work in this case because the inner iterator would need to borrow it mutably a second time, which is disallowed.

> find only the numbers where the next number is the same.

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let input = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4];

    let pairs = input
        .iter()
        .tuple_windows()
        .filter_map(|(a, b)| if a == b { Some(a) } else { None });

    let result: Vec<_> = pairs.cloned().collect();
    assert_eq!(result, [2, 4]);
}
```

Or if you wanted something using only the standard library:

```
fn main() {
    let xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4];

    let mut prev = None;
    let pairs = xs.iter().filter_map(move |curr| {
        let next = if prev == Some(curr) { Some(curr) } else { None };
        prev = Some(curr);
        next
    });

    let result: Vec<_> = pairs.cloned().collect();
    assert_eq!(result, [2, 4]);
}
```

Comment: In the specific case of a slice, [`.windows()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Windows.html) yields a subslice as a Window, which is relatively equivalent to `tuple_windows` though not generic.